# Unknown error Undefined index: catch_id in /var/www/vhosts/semanticnotion.com/httpdocs/fish/allmycatch.php on line 7

Tags: php

I am retrieving data from mysql. In web browser it works perfect but when i checked the url in my terminal it gives me the following error.

```
Undefined index:  catch_id in /var/www/vhosts/semanticnotion.com/httpdocs/fish/allmycatch.php on line 7
```

you can also check my URL http://semanticnotion.com/fish/allmycatch.php?ud_id=123456789&catch_id=8 in your browser as well as in your terminal using this command

```
curl http://semanticnotion.com/fish/allmycatch.php?ud_id=123456789&catch_id=8
```

and you will see the error message in terminal 
my code is below

```
$ud_id=$_GET['ud_id'];
$catch_id=$_GET['catch_id'];
$query="SELECT catch_id,catch_name,catch_details,longitude,latitude,time,image
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN mycatch m ON u.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE u.ud_id ='$ud_id' AND m.catch_id >'$catch_id'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
//while ($table = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
while ($table = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` is being interpreted by your shell as a command separator. You need to quote/escape the argument.

```
curl 'http://semanticnotion.com/fish/allmycatch.php?ud_id=123456789&catch_id=8'
```